# "do" multiple things in a function

Tags: haskell

**I'm new.**

So i got this working:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo s = do replace "aoa" "a" s
```

*(Typing `foo "aoa"` returns `"a"`)*
But when i add another replace:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo s = do replace "aoa" "a" s
           replace "uou" "u" s
```

*(Typing `foo "aoa"` returns `"aoa"`)*

Everything breaks and i get this warning:

```
A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ‘Char’
Suppress this warning by saying ‘_ <- replace "aoa" "a" s’
or by using the flag -fno-warn-unused-do-bind
```

Since i don't want to suppress the warning, this error message says nothing to me.

What am i missing?

**Edit1**
Examples:

```
"aoaaoa" -> "aa"   //Affected
"uouaoa" -> "ua"   //Affected
"aua" -> "aua"     //Not affected
```

Comment: Are you just trying to print two lines? Your `foo` function is pure so it cannot have side effects: it can only receive a string value and return a string. It can't affect the outside world.

Comment: @ChadGilbert I'm trying to replace a set of characters in a String with another set of characters. I'm not printing anything.

Comment: @Olian04 Can you add some examples in your question ?

Comment: Are you trying to do two consecutive replacements? It looks like you want `replace "uou" "u" (replace "aoa" "a" s)`. You probably don't want to use `do` notation for this.

Comment: Another common way to write this would be as a composition of two `replace` calls: `foo = replace "uou" "u" . replace "aoa" "a"`. This scales a little better to arbitrarily many `replace` calls, but there are other ways that are even nicer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use `do` notation to achieve a simple string replacement. But since strings are Monads, the compiler is assuming that you meant to use the string as a Monad and giving you an error message with that assumption.

If you want to simply chain together two calls to `replace`, you could write:

```
foo s = replace "uou" "u" (replace "aoa" "a" s)
```

Comment: ohh, so the first replace is using the answer from the second replace as its parameter?

Comment: Correct, based on your question, that's what I assumed you were after.

Comment: So if there are lets say, more than one occurrence, or no occurrence of "aoa". Will this still work?

Comment: That depends on your definition of `replace`. Is that a custom function or are you importing it from another package?

Answer (score 2):

do-notation is for "monad stuff". In this case I would prefer to just chain function calls together.

```
foo :: String -> String
foo s =
    let s' = replace "aoa" "a" s in
    replace "uou" "u" s'
```

Since Haskell variables are immutable, we cannot update `s` with a new value and must instead create a new variable every time. A common idiom is to add a `'` to the end of a variable name - its a valid variable name in Haskell.

You could also do it like this:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo s =
    let s'  = replace "aoa" "a" s  in
    let s'' = replace "uou" "u" s' in
    s''
```